# How do I scroll to an element within a div with overflow-y

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

I have a div which has its `max-height` set to 300px, thus whenever its content exceeds the amount, it shows a scrollbar. Now I want to be able to click a button and scroll to an element within that div. I know I can set the main scrollbar, but I'm not sure if it's possible to manipulate one generated for my div container.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px; overflow: hidden" class="card-block pt-0 pb-0">
        <div class="row" style="min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px;">
            <div class="col-5" style="overflow-y: auto; min-height: 300px;border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px;">
                <div class="pt-3 pb-3" style=" max-height: 300px;">
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                    <div id="scroll-here">content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to scroll to the div with id "scroll-here"?

I'm using Angular 5 and Bootstrap 4 if that's of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to scroll to the span

```
$(#id_of_div_with_scroll).scrollTop($("#your_span_id").offset().top);
```

Comment: This manipulates the main browser scrollbar, correct? I want to manipulate one generated on the div with overflow-y: auto;

Comment: every time you mention jquery with angular a dev died ^^

Comment: Oh ok. for that, instead of $(window) use $("#id_of_div_with_scroll")

Comment: @BleachedAnus please select the answer as right if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's just:

```html
<a href="#scroll-here">Click me</a>

<div style="min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px; overflow: hidden" class="card-block pt-0 pb-0">
  <div class="row" style="min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px;">
    <div class="col-5" style="overflow-y: auto; min-height: 300px;border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px;" id="scroll-container">
      <div class="pt-3 pb-3" style=" max-height: 300px;">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div id="scroll-here">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want it animated then:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $("#scroll-container").animate({ scrollTop: $('#scroll-here').offset().top });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>

<div style="min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px; overflow: hidden" class="card-block pt-0 pb-0">
  <div class="row" style="min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px;">
    <div class="col-5" style="overflow-y: auto; min-height: 300px;border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px;" id="scroll-container">
      <div class="pt-3 pb-3" style=" max-height: 300px;">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div id="scroll-here">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```